# Is there any generic way of converting the four array values into an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to push the data of four array values into an array of objects in javascript?

```
   // Required input

columnHeaders=['deviceName','Expected','Actual','Lost']
machine=['machine 1','machine 2','machine 3','machine 4','machine 5']
data=[
    {expectedData:[600,400,500,200,100],label:'Expected'},
    {actualData:[500,300,400,100,50],label:'Actual'},
    {LostData:[100,100,100,100,50],label:'Lost'}
]
```

// Expected output

```
tableData=[
{deviceName:"machine 1",Expected:600,Actual:500,Lost:100},
{deviceName:"machine 2",Expected:400,Actual:300,Lost:100},
{deviceName:"machine 3",Expected:500,Actual:400,Lost:100},
{deviceName:"machine 4",Expected:200,Actual:100,Lost:100},
{deviceName:"machine 5",Expected:100,Actual:50,Lost:50} ]
```

I have tried by directly passing keys as hard coded value, but i just wanted to know any generic way of solving this problem statement? Please help me solve this.

```
//tried solution
   let array=[];let obj={};
for(let i=0;i<machine.length;i++){
        var expected = data[0].expectedData[i];
        var actual = data[1].actualData[i];
        var lost = data[2].LostData[i];
    obj ={[columnHeaders[0]]:machine[i],[columnHeaders[1]]:expected,[columnHeaders[2]]:actual,[columnHeaders[3]]:lost}
    console.log(obj);
    array.push(obj);
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: no, for arrays like yours

Comment: No there isn't, because your structure is not generic in any way

Comment: will be passing those arrays into method like this - createDataSet(machine,data,columnHeaders)

Comment: can you change your input data?

Comment: No, this is how the input data we are getting from api call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud reduce the array, but I suggest to use a more streamlined format, like same named keys for the value arrays.

This approach take the `machine` array first to geenerate an array of object with a single propery and this array is the start value for reducing the data array (which could be shortened to a single array with only objects without nesting structures).

```js
var columnHeaders = ['deviceName', 'Expected', 'Actual', 'Lost'],
    machine = ['machine 1', 'machine 2', 'machine 3', 'machine 4', 'machine 5'],
    data = [{ expectedData: [600, 400, 500, 200, 100], label: 'Expected' }, { actualData: [500, 300, 400, 100, 50], label: 'Actual' }, { LostData: [100, 100, 100, 100, 50], label: 'Lost' }],
    result = data.reduce(
        (r, { label, ...o }) => Object.values(o)[0].map((v, i) => ({ ...(r[i] || {}), [label]: v })),
        machine.map(v => ({ [columnHeaders[0]]: v }))
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

is not the best way, but for you data you can try

```
let columnHeaders=['deviceName','Expected','Actual','Lost']
let machine=['machine 1','machine 2','machine 3','machine 4','machine 5']
let data=[
    {expectedData:[600,400,500,200,100],label:'Expected'},
    {actualData:[500,300,400,100,50],label:'Actual'},
    {LostData:[100,100,100,100,50],label:'Lost'}
]

let tableData = machine.reduce((acc, item, key)=>{

        acc.push({
            [columnHeaders[0]]: item,
            [columnHeaders[1]]:data[0].expectedData[key],
            [columnHeaders[2]]:data[1].actualData[key],
            [columnHeaders[3]]:data[2].LostData[key],
        })

        return acc
}, [])
```